# Find all docs where field of type double is equal to empty string

Tags: elasticsearch

## Problem

I'm trying to find all documents that have a particular field set to the empty string.

But this field is of type `double` and that complicates things...

I can't use `term` or `match` query because the field is of type `double`. I get a `number_format_exception`.

I'm currently using the following:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                   "exists": {
                        "field": "my_double_field"
                    }
                }
            ]
            
        }
    },
    "size": 100
}
```

This returns all docs where `my_double_field` is equal to `""` AND the docs where `my_double_field` does not exist at all.

## Question

Is there a query to return docs if and only if this field is set to `""`?

Comment: What do you want to do once you find them out?

Comment: @Val I'm not entirely sure why that matters, but I will remove the field completely if it is equal to `""`.

Comment: It matters, see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to remove the field, then you can simply hit the [`_update_by_query` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) and iterate over all your documents and remove the field if it matches an empty string. There's no query that will allow you to only select those documents, but at least you can iterate over all documents and only update the ones that contain those values.

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
    if (ctx._source.my_double_field == '') {
      ctx._source.remove('my_double_field');
    }
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer.  This is actually what I am already doing.  I was just wondering if there was a quicker way.  Good to know there's not!

Comment: The correct way would be to have [`ignore_malformed: false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) and [`coerce: false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html)  in your mapping to make sure that the document is rejected.

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at these!  Thanks for the info.  I will be updating the mappings as soon as I remove all of these strings. :)

Comment: Yes, it was working, but was taking a few days to scan everything. I updated the mappings to include `coerce` and `ignore_malformed`. Then the script started failing.  But the good thing is that all of the IDs with `""` were logged, so now I can update them directly.  Thanks for checking!

Comment: Oh, sorry. Have not posted on here much. 